# Split columns in a dataframe into a column that contains text not numbers and a column that contains numbers not text in R

Tags: r, string, split

Here is a simplified version of data I am working with:

```
a<-c("There are 5 programs", "2 - adult programs, 3- youth programs","25", " ","there are a number of programs","other agencies run our programs")
b<-c("four", "we don't collect this", "5 from us, more from others","","","")
c<-c(2,6,5,8,2,"")
df<-cbind.data.frame(a,b,c)
df$c<-as.numeric(df$c)
```

I want to keep both the text and numbers from the data b/c some of the text is important

expected output:

[image]

What I think makes sense is the following:

1. id all columns that have text in them, perhaps in a list (because some columns are just numbers)
2. subset columns from step 1 to a new dataframe lets call this df1
3. delete the subsetted columns in df1 from df
4. split all the columns in df1 into 2 columns, one that keeps the text and one that has the number.
5. bind the new spit columns from df1 into the orginal df

What I am struggling with is steps 1-2 and 4. I am okay with the characters (e.g., - and ') being excluded or included. There is additional processing I have to do after (e.g., when there are multiple numbers in a column after splitting I will need to split and add these and also address the written numbers), but those are things I can do.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Please provide the expected output. The question is confusing

Comment: All your columns are text, including column `c`. Please mind that

Comment: added the expected output and changed the original data to clarify that the c column is numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution using regular expression:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    a.text = gsub("(^|\\s)\\d+", "", a),
    a.num = str_extract_all(a, "\\d+"),
    b.text = gsub("(^|\\s)\\d+", "", b),
    b.num = str_extract_all(b, "\\d+") 
  ) %>% 
  select(c(4:7,3))
                              a.text a.num                     b.text b.num  c
1                 There are programs     5                       four        2
2  - adult programs,- youth programs  2, 3      we don't collect this        6
3                                       25  from us, more from others     5  5
4                                                                            8
5     there are a number of programs                                         2
6    other agencies run our programs                                        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do with my preferred tools. The solution will work with *arbitrary numbers* of *arbitrarily named* character and non-character columns.

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.3 used here
library(magrittr)   # piping used to improve readability

num <- \(x) stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\d+", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  apply(1L, \(x) sum(as.integer(x), na.rm = TRUE))
txt <- \(x) stringr::str_remove_all(x, "\\d+") %>% 
  stringr::str_squish()

setDT(df)[, lapply(
  .SD, \(x) if (is.character(x)) data.table(txt = txt(x), num = num(x)) else x)]
```

which returns

> ```
>                                 a.txt a.num                     b.txt b.num     c
>                                <char> <int>                    <char> <int> <num>
> 1:                 There are programs     5                      four     0     2
> 2: - adult programs, - youth programs     5     we don't collect this     0     6
> 3:                                       25 from us, more from others     5     5
> 4:                                        0                               0     8
> 5:     there are a number of programs     0                               0     2
> 6:    other agencies run our programs     0                               0    NA
> ```

#### Explanation

- `num()` is a function which uses the regular expression `\\d+` to extract all strings which consist of contiguous digits (aka *integer numbers*), coerces them to *type integer*, and computes the *rowwise* sum of the extracted numbers (as requested in OP's last sentence).
- `txt()` is a function which removes all strings which consist of contiguous digits (aka *integer numbers*), removes whitespace from start and end of the strings and reduces repeated whitespace inside the strings.
- `\(x)` is a new shortcut for `function(x)` introduced with R version 4.1
- The next steps implement OP's proposed approach in [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax, by and large:

  - `lapply(.SD, ...)` loops over each column of `df`.
  - if the column is character both functions `txt()` and `num()` are applied. The two resulting vectors are turned into a data.table as a partial result. Note that `cbind()` cannot be used here as it would return a character matrix.
  - if the column is non-character it is returned *as is*.
  - The final result is a data.table where the column names have been renamed *automagically*.
  - This approach keeps the relative position of columns.